# Matlab rat function in Python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a Python version of Matlab's `rat` function? I've tried looking and the seemingly closest I've found is Python's `fractions.Fraction.from_float` method within the `fractions` module. However, it doesn't seem to be implementing the same algorithm.

It doesn't seem to be too difficult to implement a function by hand following [this Matlab reference page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html#bt8x977), but I was wondering if there was a built-in function or a standard library version for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay inside of the standard library, you might want to look at the `fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator()` method:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction.from_float(0.8)
Fraction(3602879701896397, 4503599627370496)

>>> fractions.Fraction.from_float(0.8).limit_denominator()
Fraction(4, 5)
```

If you're migrating from Matlab you probably want some outside help from numpy, scipy and sympy. Sympy has a nice .nsimplify method which also does "the right thing" for fraction approximation:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.nsimplify(0.8)
4/5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! This might be a bit of a long shot, but are there any algorithmic differences between the two implementations? I'm just asking because I was testing the two out with the same value (10.123 in this case) and Matlab gives me 1893/187 whereas Python gives me 10123/1000.

Comment: The algorithms appear similar but they are parameterized differently. You can get the 1893/187 from `Fraction` by specifying a suitable argument to `limit_denominator`. `nsimplify` also takes a `tolerance` argument. So unfortunately I don't know of a way to guarantee the same behaviour as `rat` in all cases.